# $F$ a finite field of $p^n$ elements. Suppose $F^\times=\langle x \rangle$. Then $\phi(x)=x^{p^r}$ for automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime and $F$ a finite field of $p^n$ elements. Suppose $F^\times=\langle x \rangle$. Let $\phi$ be an automorhpism of $F$. Then prove that $\phi(x)=x^{p^r}$ for some integer $r$. How to prove? Thanks.

If you use theorems in Galois theory, could you give citations (which page on which book or website) for me to study?

Comment: Give us a bit of background. How much Galois theory have you covered up to this point?

Comment: $F$ is an extension of degree $p$ of the field ${\mathbb F}_p$ of order $p$ and there is a result in Galois theory that says that $F$ has a at most $n$ distinct automorphisms. But there are $n$ distinct automorphisms of the type you describe, so that must be the lot!

Comment: This can also be done without much Galois theory (well, I would reproduce the necessary results without using Galois theory concepts, which is kinda silly, but can be done :-)), so I repeat: what is your backgroud up to this point?